# Queue STL in C++ implements the queue using Circular Arrays or Linked Lists

Tags: c++, stl, queue

Since the queue can be implemented both ways, I wonder which is being used by the Queue STL.

Answer (score 2):

A `queue` is a container adaptor; it provides queue-like behavior using a different container for the underlying storage. Either `deque` or `list` are suitable for the underlying storage of a queue.  See http://eel.is/c++draft/queue for all the gory details.

Neither is a circular array.

Answer (score 0):

Checking some documentation, the complexity of insertion for this type of container is constant, if you use a vector you can't have a constant complexity because you could need resize vector, then it use a linked list.